# finding the value of $F(x)$ from the given graph of $f(x)$

Tags: calculus, integration

I was given the following question:

> [image]
>   The graph of the continuous function $f$ consists of $3$ line segments and a semi-circle centered at point $(5,1)$, as shown above. If $F(x)$ is an anti-derivative of $f(x)$ such that $F(0)=2$, what is the value of $F(9)$?

I am not sure what to do here. To begin with, if $F$ is an anti-derivative of $f$. Isn't it the area function? If so, then how is $F(0)=2$? If not, then what am I mixing up here? And, once this is understood, how should I tackle the rest of the problem?

Comment: Hint: $F(x) = 2 + \int\limits_0^x f(a)da$, and the second summand *is* the area.

Comment: If you differentiate a cdf or another function the constant is disappearing. So you need a condition to derive the cdf from the pdf.

Comment: so the 2 just tells what the constant is in the antiderivative

Comment: Yes, that´s true.